# Show references lens of a property or method in typescript, like in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, codelens

I've started angular2 (using typescript) project in visual studio code. The project is big and sometimes I find it hard to remember where a certain function or class is called.

I'm used to develop in visual studio 2015, with the use of the references count, the ide is great at showing all the references of a class and properties. 
[image]

Is there a plugin or a way to achieve this in vs code for an angular2 project?

I still haven't tried it on vs 2015, is this available in vs 2015 when coding in typescript for an ng2 application?

Comment: VS Code 1.8.x + Supports this feature. Just go to the settings and turn on the codelens

Answer (score 1):

[Unfortunately the answer is no for now](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/5249694-add-codelens-support-for-javascript-typescript-an)

### Add Codelens support for Javascript, Typescript and CSS

[image]